# Git submodules and composer clarification

Tags: git, github

I have created a php project. In this project under vendor/ I have included using composer some
other 3rd party modules. I think they came with a .git folder.

Finally I decided to add my code under git. But now I have problems. Some of this 3rd party modules came with a .git folder some without ( idk the reason ). why this happen any clue ?

In my root folder I have nothing in .gitmodules.

When I do `git status` I get:

`#       modified:   vendor/somemodule (modified content)`

What should I do in this case, what's the best way to handle this. I want to be able to still be
updated about the changes in those libraries and also keep a track of those modules in my repository ( beanstalk ) which when merged to master branch will upload to live server.

Any ideas, any links to read would be helpful. I don't even know if this are submodules or not yet.

an image with my vendor:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Check first if those are submodule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24242793/6309

Comment: If I do `git ls-tree HEAD` in the root don't get any 160000 if I enter in a directory in vendor some have 160000 some don't have

Comment: @VonC I've updated my post with an image. should I map them in .gitmodule all of them. What would you do in this case :) ?

Comment: I would check for the exact nature of the changes in the submodule, to see if those changes can be ignored or should be pushed to their upstream repo: `cd vendor/somemodule ; git status`

Comment: I think can be ignored the changes. but when trying to deploy I get an error saying that a module from there has no mapping in .gitmodules and second I don't like the way they are, some submodules some not.

Comment: It seams there's a problem with composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md saw it too late. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OP Marius.C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2209160/marius-c) confirms:

> When I do git status I get:

```
# modified: vendor/somemodule (modified content)
```

That does mean `vendor/somemodule` is a submodule (see "[Strange Icon and Entry after corrupt commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242793/6309)").

But the root issue seems to be an [issue with composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md), as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424969/git-submodules-clarification#comment37793310_24424969) by the OP.

#### Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?

> The general recommendation is no. 
>   The `vendor` directory (or wherever your dependencies are installed) should be added to `.gitignore/svn:ignore/etc`.

Considering the changes seen so far seem to be not important, ignoring `vendor` should be the best approach.