# Should I put my library folder in Vendor folder for composer?

Tags: git, composer-php

I am using Composer and was wondering where I put my library folder.

Should I keep it separate from the Vendor folder or put it in the Vendor folder?
If you do put it in the Vendor folder, should I push that to Git because I read that it is a bad practice to push your vendor folder up to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vendor` folder is generally ignored, as I explained in "[Git submodules and composer clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24429317/6309)".

So if you have to, put the `library` folder outside of the `vendor` folder.

That being said, check that you don't put too many or too large binaries in it.
And if you depend on library *sources*, consider including only [**submodules**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), because there are just an [entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242793/6309) (very lightweight).